# Android files served by localhost won't open without network connection

Tags: php, android

I run a php web application on localhost on a tablet running android. Everything works fine but when there is no wifi connection the pdf files served by localhost don't open in browser.
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: "no wifi connection the pdf files served by localhost don't open in browser"  if no internet how can it serve ?

Comment: But the application is served on localhost of android device! No need for internet connection. Actually this was the reason we installed an http server on the device, to be able use the app even without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localhost, There must be **network connection** such as WIFI or USB Tethreting ( not INTERNET ) for data communication from your Server to your Device.